# Give synthesis freedom to choose signal

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl

Is there some sort of don't care in Verilog (or VHDL) where I can say:

"Use either signal A or signal B, I don't really care because they would be functionally equivalent. Just do your best, good luck!"

**Example:**

```
module example
    (input wire [1:0] idx,  
     // Sometimes an address of 3 shows up, but in this case the 
     // output is irrelevant (not used/read).
     output wire [2+8-1:0] out);

    reg [8*3-1:0] mem_r;  // 3 words of 1 byte each, imagine content
    wire [1:0] idx_restricted;

    always @* begin
        if(idx == 3) begin
            idx_restricted = 2'b00;
        end else begin
            idx_restricted = idx;
        end
    end

    assign output = {idx, mem_r[8*idx_restricted +: 8]};  
    // ***Here "idx" could be either idx, or idx_restricted***
endmodule
```

Without the idx_restricted there is an out-of-bounds to the mem_r.

Anyone know of something like this?

Comment: Could you explain more? Can you paste an example? Though, if the signals are equivalent why do you even consider choosing the other one?

Comment: An OR gate perhaps?

Comment: I didn't really want to add an example because I wanted to keep the question general. But I tried to come up with an example to clarify the question.

Comment: @Wossname: Not sure how that would be. It seems to me that that would just add more logic. In that case I, as the one writing the code, should choose one of the signals in some arbitrary way instead.

Comment: I don't know if this would actually work, but in VHDL you could create "constant flag : std_logic := '-';" then set your assignment to be "output <= idx when flag='1' else idx_restricted"

Answer (score 3):

No. As far as VHDL is concerned, they are either the same signal, or a different signal. Even if you know that they (for instance) start from the same signal and go through two different functionally identical gates, or that they are two equivalent pins from an I/O block of a general purpose chip, and you can choose what they do later in software.

You could do it mandronically, by having two different architectures, one using signal A, one using B, and see which gave you the better synthesis. That will work for one uncertain signal, but would rapidly become tedious if you needed to compare dozens, or permutations of dozens. That's when you need to fire up the 'generate' statement, to create those architectures for you.

If it's the case that you are assigning bus pins, then you just have to make an intelligent stab at what's likely to be best, and let the tools sort it out. Only start optimising the pins if you get a routing fail.

Comment: mandrolically? Mandrolic: adj. a long and tedious task performed manually rather than automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a separate idx_restricted variable. Verilog generates an X if the index into mem_r is out of bounds, and that becomes a don't care.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided example those two signals are different. If the design can work with both of them, then from synthesis/timing point of view you should use `idx`. This is because `idx_restricted`, which technically is *almost* like the `idx`, still needs decoder when `idx == 3`. That's just adding another level of logic.

Anyway, synthesis tools will usually do the right job and very often optimize the logic in a good manner. I wouldn't worry about it, unless you are really looking at the performance / timing issues.

Comment: I'm mostly curious. Also, what says that shallower logic is better. If congested I would guess it could possibly be easier to route if I use idx_restricted instead of having to route idx passed the decoder?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the answer to your question is 'yes'. A synthesiser can treat an X value as a don't care, which can lead to better minimisation. In practice, though, this is a really bad idea. The fundamental issue is that simulation treats X values as 'unknown' or 'wildcard', which is not the same as the synthesiser interpretation. This means that an RTL simulation of a faulty design can (incorrectly) pass, while the netlist simulation can (correctly) fail. Equivalence checkers can also fail to spot the bug, you may get incorrect code coverage reports, and so on.

Mike Turpin wrote a good paper on ths years ago - see [here](https://static.docs.arm.com/arp0009/a/Verilog_X_Bugs.pdf).

I'm assuming, of course, that you can rewrite your code to push through an X in the relevant case.

Comment: Yes, an X can be used to represent a "don't care" casein synthesis for a given signal, but it can't be used to say "I don't care which signal you use". There is no such thing as a 'wildcard' in simulation, it is unknown.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: wildcard: see Verilog `casex`/`casez`, and VHDL `case?`; to "don't care which signal": mux, with one of the inputs `X` for the case in which "the output is irrelevant"

Comment: `casex` and `casez` are primarily used to control **synthesis**. You said "**simulation** treats X...as...'wildcard'. And you didn't say anything about `casex` or `casez` in your original answer, nor did you clarify that by 'X values' you meant values in a literal expression used in a `casex` or `casez`. And the simulator will never say "the output is irrelevant" it will say "the output is unknown". Words have meaning, and the meaning matters.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Yes, *simulation* treats `X` as 'unknown or wildcard'. 'wildcard' is a common generic term used when describing `casex` and `casez`. See, for example, Cummings' `casex` paper. Note that all his papers are about simulation, not synthesis. I  didn't have to say anything about `casex`, because anyone who uses Verilog regularly will know what 'wildcard' means. I said nothing about 'irrelevant'; I simply *quoted* the OP's requirement. If you really object to my answer, read Turpin's paper, which I linked.

Comment: Remember that you are **not** writing for someone who "uses Verilog regularly"...you are trying to help a newcomer. When you say "treats X values as 'unknown' or 'wildcard'" the structure of the phrase makes it unclear. Does the simulator make an arbitrary, random choice between 'unknown' or 'wildcard'? If the input of an AND gate is 'X' is that treated as a 'wildcard'?  If the conditional part of a ternary operator evaluates to 'X' does the simulator arbitrarily decide which of the choices to return? You may like 'wildcard' but IEEE Std 1364 uses 'do-not-care'.